# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type MyRunnable

Tags: java, static-methods

Here is the whole code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Test<E extends Comparable<E>>{

    ThreadLocal<ArrayList<E>>arraylist=new ThreadLocal<ArrayList<E>>(){
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<E> initialValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return super.initialValue();
            ArrayList<E>arraylist=new ArrayList<E>();
            for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
            arraylist.add((E) new Integer(i));
            return arraylist;
        }
    };


    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        private Test mytest;

        public MyRunnable(Test test){
            mytest=test;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
                System.out.println("before"+mytest.arraylist.toString());
                ArrayList<E>myarraylist=(ArrayList<E>) mytest.arraylist.get();
                myarraylist.add((E) new Double(Math.random()));
                mytest.arraylist.set(myarraylist);
                System.out.println("after"+mytest.arraylist.toString());
            }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test test=new Test<Double>();

        System.out.println(test.arraylist.toString());

        new Thread(new MyRunnable(test)).start();

        new Thread(new MyRunnable(test)).start();

        System.out.println(arraylist.toString());

    }

}
```

my questions are:

1. Why `new Thread(new MyRunnable(test)).start();` cause the error:
   `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type MyRunnable`?
2. What does the term "static reference" refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Why new Thread(new MyRunnable(test)).start(); cause the error:
>   Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type MyRunnable?
>
> Answer 1: Because you can not instantiate inner class in static context directly.`main` method is always `static`.
>   To Avoid this error you can use outer class reference to initialize inner class which binds that inner class to specified reference.

```
 new Thread(test.new MyRunnable(test)).start();//Use test object to create new
```

> Question 2: What does the term "static reference" refer to?
>
> Answer 2: `new MyRunnable(test)` is not static you will have to make `MyRunnable` static in order to access like this.

**You are using generics in most inefficient way :)**

Declare `MyRunnable<E>` Because `Generics in static context is different than in normal object context`

If I understand you correctly you want `MyRunnable` class to understand `E` that is passed to `Test` class.
This is not possible like you are doing.

You will have to make `MyRunnable` to understand `E` and then you can access it.

```
static class MyRunnable<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Runnable {

    private Test<E> mytest;

    public MyRunnable(Test<E> test) {
        mytest = test;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Test<Double> test = new Test<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> doubles = test.arraylist.get();
        doubles.add(new Double(Math.random()));//No type cast needed
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

Comment: if i add the keyword to the MyRunable,there will be another problem,i can not use the generic type parmeter,E, within it.Any idea?thx

Comment: like:static class MyRunnable <E extends Comparable<E>>implements Runnable?But,what is the relationship between the type E here and the E in the Test<E extends Comparable<E>>? And,Do my understanding make sense?Because Test test=new Test<Double>();,so the MyRunnable's E is also Double?

Comment: @kaiwiiho added some explanation and code snippet hope it clears your doubt

Comment: thx.But,in ur code,u specify the type into Double.And,my intention is to make the code suitable for any type.And i have try the type as generic type,it works.I just do not understand that though i set nothing in the MyRunable but just parameterize it with a Test instance,the MyRunnable seems to accept the Test instance's E type as its E type.Can u explain it for me?thx

Comment: Yes This code is suitable for any type that extends `Comparable` e.g. `Integer`, `String` etc

Comment: pls watch my new edit.U mean it is suitable for any Comparable？But u specify it in the function,run().

Comment: Update the answer please check.

Comment: nice answer,thx!But,in ur answer,what do u mean by  using generics in most inefficient way?About Performance or grammer?

Comment: Whole idea of generics is to avoid cast and ensure type safety you were not doing it by making MyRunnable to use usafe types.

Answer (score 1):

you declared the MyRunnable class inside your Test class without the `static` keyword, thus it is an "inner" class.  you can only instantiate an inner class within an instance of an outer class.  you are trying to instantiate it in a static method, hence there is no outer instance.  my guess is that your intent is for the MyRunnable class to be a nested class not an inner class, so you should just add the static keyword to the class definition.

Comment: the static method is just the main function for testing.In my real running case,i do not need to run MyRunnable in the static method.

Comment: if i add the keyword to the MyRunable,there will be another problem,i can not use the generic type parmeter,E, within it.Any idea?thx

Comment: @kaiwiiho - yes, in that case, you need to parameterize the MyRunnable class, i.e. `MyRunnable<E...>`.

Comment: u mean with the keyword,static and parametierzing the MyRunnable?

Comment: @kaiwiiho - yes, that's what i mean

Comment: like:static class MyRunnable <E extends Comparable<E>>implements Runnable?But,what is the relationship between the type E here and the E in the Test<E extends Comparable<E>>?

Comment: Do my understanding make sense?Because Test test=new Test<Double>();,so the MyRunnable's E is also Double?

Comment: @kaiwiiho - there is no implicit relationship.  however, in the MyRunnable constructor you would only accept a Test paramaterized by the same E, thus establishing a relationship for a given instance.

Comment: would u mind clarify it?So,how do the myarraylist in MyRunnable know that its E is what?By the insatance of Test that paramaterized in the MyRunnable's constructor?